# C++: Управляющий символ '\a' не работает

Tags: c++, c, gcc

У меня есть небольшое консольное приложение, которое загадывает число от 0 до 100, а пользователь пытается его угадать. Я решил добавить в него небольшую фичу: когда пользователь угадывает число, раздаётся звуковой сигнал. Делается это управляющим символом `'\a'` .

Вот код:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    srand(time(NULL));

    int guess;
    int secret = rand() % 101;
    do {
        cout << "Попробуй угадать число от 0 до 100" << endl;
        cin >> guess;
        if (guess > secret)
        {
            cout << "Многовато" << endl; 
        } else if (guess < secret) {
            cout << "Маловато" << endl;
        }
    } while (guess != secret);
    cout << "\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\aКрасавчик! Ты угадал!!!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

При сборке с GCC под openSUSE звук не срабатывает. Звуковая карта есть, это точно. Можно ли как-то заставить это работать?

Comment: А почему вы считаете, что это обязано работать? Интерпретация контрольных символов — добрая воля консоли, оно может вполне и не выдавать звук, а сигнализировать как-то по-другому (например, миганием) или вовсе игнорировать контрольные символы. Посмотрите в настройки консоли.

Comment: Windows 7 исправно бибкает

Comment: Эм.. Звуковая карта вроде не используется для этого звука?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

времена [«железных» терминалов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB) давно миновали.

решение о том, что именно делать при получении того или иного символа, программы-эмуляторы телетайпов (tty — teletype, другие названия: консоль, (виртуальный) терминал) принимают, в частности, на основе своих конфигурационных файлов.